# How do I implement a generic polymorphism to print the length? That's what they asked me to do

Tags: c++, function, class, constructor, polymorphism

They asked me to implement a generic polymorphism to print the length and I don't know how to do it. I thought that for polymorphism it had to be more than one class, but they asked for onw class only

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Line {
private:
    double x1, x2;
    double y1, y2;
    double z1, z2;
    double length;
public:
    Line(double a, double b, double c, double d, double e, double f):x1(a), x2(d), y1(b), y2(e), z1(c), z2(f){
        length = sqrt(pow(x2-x1, 2) + pow(y2-y1, 2) + pow(z2-z1, 2));
    }

    ~Line(){cout << endl << "destroying line";}
};

int main() {
    Line line1(2,3,4,9,7,12);
    Line line2(12,16,7,25,32,16);
    Line line3(5,2,13,24,18,15);
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the requirement is to implement a virtual method that returns the length.  The `virtual` will allow child classes to overload it (a.k.a. polymorphism).  You're setting up the capability for polymorphism.

Comment: It's not just you, I'm confused as well.  Can you post you exact requirements?

Comment: FYI, `x * x` is often more efficient than `pow(x, 2)`.  Also, the `pow` function returns floading point, so there may be some inaccuracies when converting back and forth.

Comment: Also, you'll want to declare your destructor as `virtual` to help support polymorphism.

Comment: There are two types of polymorphism: A) Compile-time: overloading a functions (i.e. different parameters) B) Run-time: same function declaration in base/derived classes but using 'virtual' word.

Comment: Generic may refer to generic programming implemented through templates in `c++`. Attach the full requirement, otherwise this seems too vague

Comment: I have never heard about "generic polymorphism" but apparently it's the same as "parametric polymorphism". A typical example of parametric polymorphism (of sorts) is an STL algorithm (parameterised by types, works on any kind of iterator ranges). It isn't entirely clear how you "implement" such a concept in this case. There is nothing type-parametric in this code. Maybe they want you to convert `Line` to a template and `double` to its type parameter. Or maybe they want a type parameter to `print_length` function template.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question as asked, first of all you need to expose the `length`, as it's currently encapsulated - you can add a function to the `public:` section of your class:

```
auto get_length() const { return length; }
```

Then you can use generic polymorphism to print the length (your "implement a generic polymorphism", taken pretty literally):

```
template <typename T>
void print_length(const T& t) {
    std::cout << t.get_length() << '\n';
}
```

Then you can prove it works by adding some calls at the bottom of `main()`:

```
print_length(line1);
print_length(line2);
print_length(line3);
```

---

All that said, it's also possible they didn't truly want "generic" polymorphism - not knowing "generic" tends to refer to polymorphism using templates - and were just expecting something like:

```
struct with_length {
    virtual ~with_length() { }
    virtual double get_length() const = 0;
};
class Line : with_length {
    ...
    double get_length() const { return length; }
};
```